# How to universally validate the method of virtual work for all pulley systems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, power, constrained-dynamics

How can it be proven that the method of virtual work for pulley constraints is true for all pulley systems, including complex pulley systems (such as block and tackle)?

Method of virtual work : The work done by all the tension forces on the blocks is zero, and likewise, the power delivered is also zero.

$Σ [ T(vector) • s(vector)]=0$

Answer (score 0):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
To see that the D'Alembert's principle is valid for Atwood machine lets look at this example.
[image]

the EOM's  for  the free body diagram

\begin{align*}
&m_1\,\ddot{z}_1=-m_1\,g+T_1\\
&m_2\,\ddot{z}_2=-m_2\,g+T_2\\
&m_3\,\ddot{z}_3=-m_3\,g+T2\\ 
\end{align*}
with  $~T_1=2\,T_2~$ the EOM's with matrix notation
\begin{align*}
  &\b M\,\begin{bmatrix}
           \ddot{z}_1 \\
           \ddot{z}_2 \\
           \ddot{z}_3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  =-g\,\begin{bmatrix}
                         m_1 \\
                         m_2 \\
                         m_3 \\
                       \end{bmatrix}+
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
   2 \\
   1 \\
   1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b C_T}\,T_2
\end{align*}

from the distribution matrix $~\b C_T~$ of the tension forces (constraint forces) , you obtain the constraint equation

\begin{align*}
 &2\,z1+z_2+z_3=0
\end{align*}
this means that this  Atwood machine  have two generalized coordinates . e.g. $~z_1~,z_2~$ thus
\begin{align*}
 &z_3=-2\,z_1-z_2\quad\Rightarrow\quad
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \delta z_1 \\
    \delta z_2 \\
    \delta z_3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    -2 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\b J}
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \delta z_1 \\
    \delta z_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\delta\b q}
\end{align*}

apply D'Alembert's principle

\begin{align*}
 & \delta\b q^T\,\b J^T\,\b C_T\,T_2 \overset{?}{=}\b 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\b J^T\,\b C_T \overset{?}{=}\b 0\\
 &\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
                   2 \\
                   1 \\
                   1 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}~\surd
\end{align*}